# How to fix boot into initramfs prompt and "mount: can't read '/etc/fstab': No such file or directory" and "No init found"?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, system-installation, init, initramfs

Installing a new system using a **GPT** partitioned disk dedicated to a single partition, **ext4** formatted, **extlinux** (version 4.05) as bootloader, Ubuntu Core version 13.10 amd64 as rootfs, and Ubuntu linux-image-3.11.0-18-generic as kernel, and extlinux-update to generate bootloader configuration.

The result after reboot (still inside a KVM based virtual machine) is an (initramfs) prompt and these messages:

```
mount: can't read '/etc/fstab': No such file or directory
mount: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /sys on /root/sys failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /proc on /root/proc failed: No such file or directory
The filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init.
No init found. Try passing init= bootarg.
```

BusyBox is v1.20.2.

Regression:

- the file system has been checked with `fsck.ext4`

#### Check for root existence

```
(initramfs) ls -l /dev/[hs]da*
ls: /dev/[hs]da*: No such file or directory
```

#### Root boot argument

```
(initramfs) cat /proc/cmdline
initrd=/boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-18-generic ro quiet BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-18-generic
```

#### Check loaded modules

```
(initramfs) cat /proc/modules
e1000 145368 0 - Live 0xffffffffa0000000
```

#### /boot folder content

```
$ sudo ls -l boot
-rw------- 1 root root 3296162 Feb 18 22:37 System.map-3.11.0-18-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1007681 Feb 18 22:37 abi-3.11.0-18-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  163258 Feb 18 22:37 config-3.11.0-18-generic
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Mar 17 20:13 extlinux
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4995000 Mar 16 23:35 initrd.img-3.11.0-18-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 5634192 Feb 18 22:37 vmlinuz-3.11.0-18-generic
```

How to make this system boot to the expected default bash prompt?

Comment: Why two init images? Can you please put this on an actual disk and try to boot it? Qemu and EFI have issues - for instance, if you do not use an EFI boot firmware image, you won't get very far at all.

Comment: And if all you want is a bash prompt you could always include bash in your initramfs...

Comment: In fact, I'm remembering looking at LARGE GPT partitions in Ubuntu and them registering as completely empty. After I held shift at reboot to get grub's selection for their live disk I was able to select the Efi option, after which I had a disk.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Modify your kernel boot parameter by setting the `root=/dev/sdaX` option. `sdaX` would be your `/` or `root` partition. Upon booting the next time, you will see that your `initramfs` tries to mount the partition before trying to access `/etc/fstab` and mounting the file systems.

See question "[Does initramfs use /etc/fstab?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92720/does-initramfs-use-etc-fstab)" for more details.

Comment: Adding `root=/dev/sdaX `improves the situation, there is no longer an `(initramfs)` but a `bash` login prompt instead.

Comment: Beside manually adding `root=/dev/sdaX` to kernel boot, I need to update `/mnt/etc/default/extlinux` and change `EXTLINUX_ROOT=""` to the suggested `EXTLINUX_ROOT="/dev/sdaX"` and run `extlinux-update` again.

Comment: If your installation uses dm-crypt, you might need to use the mapper such as `root=/dev/mapper/sdaX_crypt`. Note that `sdaX_crypt` might be different if you renamed it when setting up the crypt. At the `initramfs` prompt (after a failed boot), you can use `ls /dev` and tab completion to inspect the folder structure.

Answer (score 12):

What you need to understand about *`initramfs`* is that it is a filesystem. Since kernel 2.6 it is, basically, the only kernel-imposed filesystem ( leaving aside VFS, which is *arguably* also a filesystem ) on your machine. Your *`initramfs image`* is a disk image.

Within your *`initramfs image`* will be whatever files your distribution decided were crucial enough to require before your root disk is found. Usually that's Busybox and whatever kernel modules you need to find and mount your root device. This is isn't working for you.

There's no real mystery here though, all things considered. If you can find your way around a terminal prompt you can navigate the *`initramfs.`* But first you've gotta demystify it.

First and foremost and once again - this is just *`/.`* It's Linux root doing Linux root type things. In fact, if it is in a separate file from your kernel, it's actually already your second root device. Every Linux kernel contains a *basically* empty *`/`* all its own which it first mounts before pulling in your *`initramfs.`*

What's more *`initramfs`* is the *real* root. It is where the Linux kernel initializes userspace by execing *`init`* and subsequently renouncing all responsibility for any problem you might encounter thereafter. Your *`init`* seems to be Busybox, as are many, which means controlling its actions should be as simple as editing its accompanying shell scripts.

Then why the error about not finding *`init?`* Almost definitely this is referring to a program named *`init`* which your actual *`init`* has been instructed via shell script to exec itself into.

Most striking to me is that the kernel pseudo file systems - *`dev sys proc`* - do not mount. This is either very troubling or a very good clue. You mention KVM which leads me to question kernel capabilities, but before we go down that dark and rutted road, can we first try something else?

```
cd /root || mkdir /root
```

It strikes me that the error message is repeatedly:

> No such file or directory

Failing that you need to rebuild your *`initramfs`* image. Boot to a live disc to do so and run whatever tool your distribution provides to accomplish that end. Oh, and please *ensure* that this live disk is loaded in ***EFI*** mode.

So here's the only truly out-of-the-ordinary thing about *`initramfs - switchroot.`*

The Linux kernel provides a very special syscall intended for early userspace and handling the move from *`initramfs`* to your root disk device. It works by first mounting your root disk into a mountpoint in *`initramfs`* and then pivoting the root filesystem into it. I assume your *`initramfs's`* target mount point is *`root`* based on the way it keeps moaning about it. Why not make sure it's there?

For further investigation you're going to need to get a little gritty. Adjust your bootloader to pass ...

```
init=/bin/sh
```

... as a kernel parameter.

Comment: _...target mount point is root... Why not make sure it's there?_ I haven't got to foggiest idea how to verify this.

Comment: You dont need to anymore. Youve got bash which means youre past initramfs. But are you still in kvm?

Comment: Yes, I am still in kvm.

Comment: @ProBackup If you made it there you need to give the other guy your bounty - thats what you stated was your goal, anyway. Nevermind - youve apparently already done so. Im curious to know why you need to specify two init images - why initrd and boot? What is that? I should also like to know what, if anything, you can get out of running `efibootmgr` at your prompt in your virtual machine.

Comment: I have made a new SE question for the why: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120999/why-do-i-need-to-specify-two-init-images-initrd-and-boot-inside-kvm-to-boot Note: I do think that this KVM (Parallels Desktop v8) only has a BIOS (not UEFI) due to the BIOS boot message.

Comment: @mikeserv, I was way stuck on this issue (using `https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/776643-how-to-rescue-a-non-booting-grub-2-on-linux/` ) The addition of `init=/bin/sh` right before grub> boot totally nailed it.  Many thanks!

Comment: I like the way you throughoutly explain things. It found essencial for beginners like myself

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. What Alex said is correct.
First I adjusted my `fstab` but that didn't help. 
So, I checked my GRUB. If you have the possibility to access GRUB menu.

- Select the Linux, what you want to start and which makes trouble.
- Press 'e' and look for 'boot_image' or 'boot...root'.
- Check the '**uuid**'.
- In my case, it was wrong. I make a picture in `initramfs` by typing '`blkid`' and take the uuid on which partition my linux is installed.
- Paste the correct uuid from blkid to grub -> boot_image.

That solved my problem. After reboot my Linux needed longer time to start to check the disk. But now it works again.

I hope I could help you.

Regards