# Disk appears OK, will read/write in LiveCD, will not boot, stops at initramfs/busybox

Tags: ubuntu, boot, hard-disk, grub, initramfs

Installed Ubuntu twice and Linux Mint once onto an SSD that used to be a system disk after Ubuntu was corrupted in upgrade.

Every time, I get the same result. When I try to boot from the disk, I get a black screen with a cursor, and nothing loads.

I am able to get something to load when I choose "Boot from first hard disk" in a live CD.

However, this drops me to Busybox, and doesn't load all of the commands. I cannot `fsck`, for instance. A simple `exit` crashes the system so that `ALT + CTRL + Delete` won't restart.

[I tried the solutions here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137655/boot-drops-to-a-initramfs-prompts-busybox), trying to use an alternate superblock. I don't think it applies because the disk appears to be otherwise usable.

`fsck -b` returns clean and I've tried at least 3 superblocks with Ubuntu and Linux Mint installs. I don't think that's the issue.

I've also tried adding `root=/dev/sdc1` to my grub to [pass on to the kernel, as outlined here.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120198/how-to-fix-boot-into-initramfs-prompt-and-mount-cant-read-etc-fstab-no-su) At least, I added them to my grub parameters and updated grub [via a live CD using this method.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145241/how-do-i-run-update-grub-from-a-livecd) Perhaps this was wrong but it was all I have been able to find before this point.

So far, no dice. The machine isn't even printing different errors.

Is it possible that the SSD isn't bootable anymore, despite being able to read/write and reporting clean from a fsck?

If not, how can I fix it?

[image: errors from initramfs/busybox]

Comment: Boot from the rescue and choose *do not mount the files systems* , from the shell run `fsck` with `-f` option on your root partition

Comment: I might be confused. Rescue from Live Disk? I can't even get to the GRUB menu on the SSD to select Recovery Mode. I can only get to the above screen with the "Boot from first disk" option on the Live Disk.

Comment: the recovery mode from the advanced options of grub nenu

Comment: Yes, I can't access that. The disk doesn't boot on its own (black screen with cursor, described above), and the "boot from first disk" option gives me the above output.

Comment: see [Booting into recovery mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode) step 1 ->7 , **do not mount your root partition** and run `fsck`

Comment: Thank you for that link, but I don't think it's very helpful. As I stated, GRUB doesn't load or show a splash screen. To be thorough I followed the directions anyway, and I did so twice, once with the LiveCD and one without. Recovery mode will not load, as I said.

Comment: I booted to the LiveCD again and ran fsck again. The root partition was never mounted when I ran it. I ran it with -f like you suggested and the result was the same. I rebooted with and without using the LiveCD to boot from the disk and got the same two results.

Comment: I have the same issue except grub works. I've rebooted dozens of times fine, until yesterday. A simple "sudo reboot" and then this.

Comment: @noybman The only thing that worked for me was reformatting and making partitions that ignored the first couple of gigabytes on the disk. I never really got much of an answer but assuming that the disk had bad sectors not being detected or fixed solved the problem as best as I could. There's probably a more elegant solution but this was where I landed.

Comment: Im hoping more people review your question, I may have to post my own and toss a bounty on it, but you seem to have experiences the same thing I did. System was working great for months (as a router). I did an apt-get update & upgrade, and a sudo reboot, and this happened. I can mount the disk on ubuntu live and access the files. I'm not willing to reinstall again if ubuntu hoses itself... which apparently it did. I'm going to keep digging. (My disk is a SSD disk. So its not going to be a bad sectors issue in the standard sense)

Comment: I was very cautious about modifying the disk full well knowing it was clean and ok. It turned out to be a corrupted frub2 config. Strange that it "looked fine" but doing an grubupdate worked once I was CHROOTed